# javascript function does not execute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I do not know why it does not show an alert .

I put a break point on my controller and it returns data correctly. In my view it does not show any alert.

my view -

**HTML**:

```
<div class="well pull-right">
    <a id="btn_Pardakht" href="" class="btn btn-general " onclick=" Myfunc();">spend</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function Myfunc() {

    var url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';
    $.post(url, {
        nam: 'alex'
    }, function (data) {
        if (data)
            alert("success");
        else
            alert("error");
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction ( string nam)
{
    var data = new
    {
        sent = true
    };
    return Json(data);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';
$.post(url , { name: "John"})
.done(function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Put this in your controller  `return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<a id="btn_Pardakht" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-general " onclick="return Myfunc();">spend</a>
```

and in javascript,

```
function Myfunc() {

    var url = '/MyController/MyAction';
    $.post(url, {
        nam: 'alex'
    }, function (data) {
        if (data)
            alert("success");
        else
            alert("error");
        location.reload();
    });
    return false;
}
```

and still it is not responding.. `JSON.stringify({name: 'alex'});`

change your action like,

```
public ActionResult MyAction ( string nam)
{
    var data = new
    {
        sent = true
    };
    return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

Hope this helps.